# Visualize pattern on UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uikit

My goal is to create a text field that matches this picture:

[image]

Core idea is that:

- User can't edit pattern symbols (i.e. place cursor there)
- Pattern symbols get replaced and disappear as the user types
- There are static pattern symbols (i.e. '-')

Is there a drop-in solution for such things? I've searched over GitHub and there are a lot of libs that do UITextField formatting, but they usually just add symbols and it doesn't actually feel like a placeholder that guides user how to type.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If you want Xs to disappear and be replaced by digits one by one (and not by whole four-digit groups), you should add not four (as Robert Dresler suggests), but sixteen `UITextField`s with X placeholder in each of them.

Make the cursor jump to the next field once the current one is filled, and also make it jump to the first field that’s not filled when the user taps on any of the fields (to prevent inputting digits in random positions).

Comment: Oh, and what do I do when user removes character? I hove to kinda move everything from next text fields?

Comment: Yes, when the user deletes a character, you should move the cursor to the previous text field. I believe you can use the `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)` delegate method for detecting when the user types or deletes characters.